# Why is chess, checkers, Go, etc. in EXP but conjectured to be in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, np-complete, computability

If I tell you the moves for a game of chess and declare who wins, why can't it be checked in polynomial time if the winner does really win? This would make it an NP problem from my understanding.

Comment: You mean a complete specific game (1. e4 c5 2. Sf3 d6, ... until mate)?

Comment: @Aconcagua yes. I think that's what they mean by chess being EXP, but if not, please clarify.

Comment: I think this depends on what question you're asking about the game. Can you give a source on these comments?

Comment: Yes, please refer to the linked videos in my previous but similar question here. http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/58009/51868 and I'm just a hobbyist so I was curious on the topic.

Comment: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0213018 is another source.

Comment: Have to revise myself: Of course, the game is *not* completed - given all the moves of a completed game, it would be linear in number of moves played to check who won - stupid me...

Comment: @rb612 Your last link provides two distinct problems: given a game position, A) is there a way a player can force a win, B) which is the best move the player can make. The moves made so far are actually irrelevant (they only represent history) except for determining if certain special moves (castling, capturing en passant) are legal in the current position...

Comment: @Aconcagua ah, so the only way to check if a given move is the best is by checking all options, which is EXPTIME right? But regarding is there a way a player can force a win, wouldn't it be in NP? Because the question states "from a given position", so wouldn't it just be checking if a given move results in a forced win (i.e. mate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The number of positions you can set up with 32 pieces on a 8x8 field is *limited*. We need to consider any pawn being converted to any other piece and include any such available position, too. Of course, among all these, there are some positions that cannot be reached following the rules of chess, but this does not matter. The important thing is: we have a *limit*. Lets name this limit simply MaxPositions.

Now for any given position, let's build up a tree as follows:

- The given position is the root.
- Add any position (legal chess position or not) as child.
- For any of these children, add any position as child again.
- Continue this way, until your tree reaches a depth of MaxPositions.

I'm now too tired to think of if we need one additional level of depth or not for the idea (proof?), but heck, just let's add it. The important thing is: the tree constructed like this is *limited*.

Next step: Of this tree, remove any sub-tree that is not reachable from the root via legal chess moves. Repeat this step for the remaining children, grand-children, ..., until there is no unreachable position left in the whole tree. The number of steps must be *limited*, as the tree is limited.

Now do a breadth-first search and make any node a leaf if it has been found previously. It must be marked as such(!; draw candidate?). Same for any mate position.

How to find out if there is a forced mate? In any sub tree, if it is your turn, there must be at *least one* child leading to a forced mate. If it is the opponents move, there must be a grand child for *every* child that leads to a mate. This applies recursively, of course. However, as the tree is limited, this whole algorithm is limited.

*[sensored]*, this whole algorithm is **limited**! There *is* some constant limiting the whole stuff. So: although the limit is incredibly high (and far beyond what up-to-date hardware can handle), it is a limit (please do not ask me to calculate it...). So: our problem actually is **O(1)!!!**

The same for checkers, go, ...

This applies for the forced mate, so far. What is the best move? First, check if we can find a forced mate. If so, fine, we found the best move. If there are several, select the one with the least moves necessary (still there might be more than one...).

If there is no such forced mate, then we need to measure by some means the 'best' one. Possibly count the number of available successions to mate. Other propositions for measurement? As long as operating on this tree from top to down, we still remain limited. So again, we are **O(1)**.

Now what did we miss? Have a look at the [link](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0213018) in your comment again. They are talking about an NxN checkers! The author is varying size of the field!

So have a look back at how we constructed the tree. I think it is obvious that the tree grows exponentially with the size of the field (try to prove it yourself...).

I know very well that this answer is **not a prove** for that the problem is EXP(TIME). Actually, I admit, it is not really an answer at all. But I think what I illustrated still gives quite a good image/impression of the complexity of the problem. And as long as no one provides a better answer, I dare to claim that this is better than nothing at all...

**Addendum**, considering your comment:

Let me allow to refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME#EXPTIME-complete). Actually, it *should* be suffient to transform the other problem in *exponential* time, not polynomial as in the link, as applying the transformation + solving the resulting problem still remains exponential. But I'm not sure about the exact definition...

It is sufficient to show this for a problem of which you know already it is EXP complete (transforming any other problem to this one and then to the chess problem again remains exponential, if both transformations are exponential).

Apparently, J.M. Robson found a way to do this for NxN checkers. It must be possible for [*generalized* chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_game), too, probably simply modifying Robsons algorithm. I do not think it is possible for classical 8x8 chess, though...

O(1) applies for classical chess only, not for generalized chess. But it is the latter one for which we assume not being in NP! Actually, in my answer up to this addendum, there is one prove lacking: The size of the limited tree (if N is fix) does not grow faster than exponentially with growing N (so the answer actually is incomplete!).

And to prove that generalized chess is not in NP, we have to prove that there is no polynomial algorithm to solve the problem on a non-deterministic turing machine. This I leave open again, and my answer remains even less complete...

Comment: This is a great explanation! Thanks! Now what's making this EXP-complete? Why are we to think that chess ∉ NP considering the fact that O(1) is the time to check the answer?

Comment: Oh, by the way - if transformation really must occur in polynomial time complexity as described in wikipedia and you can transform np or exp complete problems to the classic 8x8 problem, you would have proved thad P = NP or P = EXP, respectively...

Comment: This is super helpful! Thanks for the addendum! So my last question is this: According to wikipedia, a generalized game is a "problem of determining if there is a win for the first player in a given position is EXPTIME-complete." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_game) And you say "But it is the latter [generalized chess] for which assume not being in NP!" But why doesn't the O(1) apply to this generalized chess too? If a non deterministic turing machine took an nxn chess board, gave a solution, despite its complexity being EXP, it's checking time would stay at O(1), or am I wrong?

Comment: Or am I thinking about this wrong: does EXPTIME not say anything about its complexity of *checking* correctness using a non-deterministic turing machine? Because in this case I can't see the complexity to be worst case greater than O(1), so it HAS to be in NP too, right? Or wrong? But we assume it's not in NP which is weird because to me it seems like it should be in NP

Comment: Generalized chess is not in O(1), because we have to consider game board size! If *n* (side length of the board, equal to eight for classic chess) grows, the number of possible positions grows and thus the tree built grows. And it grows exponentially in relation to n. So: O(n) is 2^n (classic chess: n is *constantly* 8, this is why O(1)!).

Comment: Oh yes, it does say something: EXPTIME is a subset of NEXPTIME, because if a problem can be solved in exponential time on a deterministic machine, it cannot be worse on a non-deterministic one. But the same as with P and NP: it is unclear if it is a real subset or if both are equal... If EXP and NEXP are not equal, then there is at least one problem that cannot be solved in exponential time on a deterministic TM, but can be on a non-deterministic one.

Comment: Ah thank you! So I understand why chess now is EXPTIME, but is generalized chess checkable in polynomial time? I don't know if this is a separate question

Comment: Imagine you have an array, always of size 8. How many steps to iterate over it? 8 ! So there is a fix constant of maximum steps you won't ever exceed, so we are O(1). Any problem, no matter how complex it is, is O(1), if there is no variable that can grow. Now lets modify the length it to any arbitrary n. Of course the number of steps to iterate over it is fix, n. But *no* fix limit m applicable for *any* n such n < b*m + c for any n > some fix n0 (definition!; chose n = b*m + c *+1*). But: n < m*n + c with e. g. m = 2 and c = 3. So iterating over arrays of arbitrary length is O(n).

Comment: Ah, makes sense - so the answer is it is in class EXPTIME but is checkable in NP time? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Yes: Ordinary chess: O(1) (fix, no n), generalized chess (GC): EXPTIME. It is EXP-complete, if you can reduce any other instance of a problem in EXP to a suitable instance of GC and solving the latter gives you the response for the former. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_game) lists generalized chess as EXP-complete, so this must be possible, e. g. solving a specific GC to find the solution for a given travelling sales man problem. Do not ask me how such a transformation would look like...

Comment: Reduce in polynomial time (wikipedia; again I'd say: exponential time should suffice..)

Answer (score 0):

> If I tell you the moves for a game of chess and declare who wins, why
>   can't it be checked in polynomial time if the winner does really win?
>   This would make it an NP problem from my understanding.

Because in order to check if the winner(white) does really win, you will have to also evaluate all possible moves that the looser(black) could've made in other to also win. That makes the checking also exponential.